# Converting String to Double Function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a string to a double from inside a function, and then return a boolean that will change based on if the conversion was successful or not. MY QUESTION is how can I check if conversion failed or not?

```
//function definitions
bool isValidDouble(string inputString);

bool isValidDouble(string inputString)
{
    //Declarations
    bool validDouble = true;
    double convertedDouble = 0;

    convertedDouble = atof(inputString.c_str());


//      validDouble = false;
//      convertedDouble = 0;

    return validDouble;
}

// CODE FROM MAIN

int main()
{
    string userInput = "";
    cout << "Please Enter a number to convert. ";
    cin >> userInput;
    isValidDouble(userInput);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `atof`, you can't. If conversion fails, it simply returns `0.0`, which is obviously still a valid number.

Comment: Any suggestions on another way of coverting that can fail and will allow me to check?

Comment: use strtod() - it allows you to check the conversion success.

Comment: Why convert? Just parse it, it's not hard -- optional sign, numbers, and optional dot followed by numbers.

Comment: If the output was `0.0` and the input was not `"0"`, `"0.0"`, etc. then that would be the condition

Comment: @Blindy its a requirement for the assignment

Comment: See [here](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#convert-string-to-num) for a pretty comprehensive set of examples on converting text to numbers. Remember, `cin` is an `istream`.

Comment: `float f; if (! (cin >> f)) {..}` This will trigger if the float was not parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`atof` doesn't provide proper error checking mechanisms, returning a `0.0` when an error occurs, but no way to differentiate between correct `0.0` and incorrect `0.0`.

For that reason, `<cstdlib>` also includes the [`std::strtod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) function, which takes an additional argument of type `char**` that is adjusted according to how far the parse got.

Example:

```
ret = std::strtod(str, &ptr);
if (ret == 0 && ptr == str)
    /* conversion failed */
else if (ret == HUGE_VAL)
    /* out of range */
else
    /* success */
```

Comment: It may or may not matter to the OP, but your use of `strtod` doesn't check that all characters (or even all non-whitespace characters) in the input were valid parts of the number, so for example you code given `1.2O3` (that's an "oh" not a "zero") would yield `1.2` and success.

Answer (score 2):

If C++11 is available, you can use [std::stod()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof). It throws an exception if the conversion can't be made.